# "Unicode-range" reported as unknown property in Stylish with Chrome 51

Tags: css, unicode, stylish

I have a short css script in Stylish that replaces Arial with a custom local font ("Dengxian") for parts of the CJK character range:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Arial;
    unicode-range: U+2E80-FFFF;
    src: local(Dengxian);
}
```

The problem is that Stylish reports "unicode-range" as an unknown property. Removing the unicode-range line makes the script work, but then it's undesirable to override Arial for Latin characters. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the extension, considering [Chrome supports `unicode-range`](http://caniuse.com/#search=unicode-range)... Perhaps you should start there.

Comment: You are right! I tried some other CSS injectors, and the code does work. However, the popular ones, by which I mean Stylish and Stylebot, are not working at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put

```
font-family: Arial !important;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information. Also, do note that the question is asking how to limit Arial for replacement only for a specific Unicode range.